# How to slowly raise playback rate of audio?

Tags: swift

I was hoping I could slowly raise the rate of the audio from 1.0 to 2.0 in a similar way to the AVAudioPlayer.setVolume(0.0, fadeDuration: )

Comment: Go ahead and do that. What's the question?

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with relevant code trials.

Answer (score -1):

Set `enableRate` to true for the AVAudioPlayer instance and then change the rate of the AVAudioPlayer.

More info:[Apple AVFoundation Rate property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1386118-rate)

Comment: this only raises it to 2.0 at that time. I want to raise it slowly over a duration